# Angular ui route - cant inject view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im having issues injecting views in Angular ui-router

Here is my route config file

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = angular
    .module("app.core");

app.config(configure);

/* @ngInject */
function configure($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    console.log("route");
    $stateProvider
        .state("login", {
            url: "/login",
            templateUtrl: "LogIn"
        }); //?<---alows you to password queryString

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

}
})();
```

and here is my html file

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

i dont see what the issue is. I dont get any errors in my console windows.Can someone please guide me to proper direction please?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your `app` module list `app.core` as a dependency? Where is your `app.core` module defined?

Comment: and syntax error - templateUtrl (instead of templateUrl)

Comment: @JanisP yes, that was it! omg ive done this so many times.... this i couldn't get my head around it to figure out whats wrong Thank you!!! <3

Comment: @Phil app.core injects all my dependencies and my main app injects login app and index app